# Arduino ESP8266: Http GET with dynamic parameters

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I am new to Arduino and I am trying to send a GET request from an ESP8266 using the Http GET method
but I am getting an error 400 http code in return.

If i added the parameter manually on the URL string, I can get successful results, but when I dynamically pass the parameter in the URL string that is where I get the error 400. below is how I do it.

```
  String userID = "";
  for (int i = 96; i < 160; ++i)
  {
      userID += char(EEPROM.read(i));
  }

  Serial.print("USERID: ");
  Serial.println(userID);

  String groupID = "";
  for (int i = 160; i < 180; ++i)
  {
      groupID += char(EEPROM.read(i));
  }
   

  Serial.print("GROUPID : ");
  Serial.println(groupID );

  String type = "plug"

  HTTPClient http;
  WiFiClient client;

  String assignedStatChange = "0";
  String url = "http://example.com/api/send-device-data";
  String urlAPI = url + "/" + userID + "/" + groupID + "/" + type ;
 
  Serial.print("Sending Request:");
  Serial.println(urlAPI);
  
  http.begin(client, urlAPI);
  int httpCode = http.GET();
  Serial.print("HTTP code:");
  Serial.println(httpCode);
```

this is the output on the serial monitor with the debug enabled

```
dhcp client start...
ip:192.168.1.22,mask:255.255.255.0,gw:192.168.1.1
*Succesfully Connected!!!
Sending Request:http://example.com/api/send-device-data/1/1/plug
[HTTP-Client][begin] url: http://example.com/api/send-device-data/1
[HTTP-Client][begin] host: example.com port: 80 url: /api/send-device-data/1
[HTTP-Client][sendRequest] type: 'GET' redirCount: 0
[HTTP-Client] connected to example.com:80
[HTTP-Client] sending request header
 
-----
GET /api/send-device-data/1-----
[HTTP-Client][handleHeaderResponse] RX: 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request'
[HTTP-Client][handleHeaderResponse] RX: 'Date: Thu, 04 Mar 2021 10:27:29 GMT'
[HTTP-Client][handleHeaderResponse] RX: 'Server: Apache'
[HTTP-Client][handleHeaderResponse] RX: 'Upgrade: h2,h2c'
[HTTP-Client][handleHeaderResponse] RX: 'Connection: Upgrade, close'
[HTTP-Client][handleHeaderResponse] RX: 'Accept-Ranges: bytes'
[HTTP-Client][handleHeaderResponse] RX: 'Vary: Accept-Encoding'
[HTTP-Client][handleHeaderResponse] RX: 'Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'
[HTTP-Client][handleHeaderResponse] RX: 'Pragma: no-cache'
[HTTP-Client][handleHeaderResponse] RX: 'Expires: 0'
[HTTP-Client][handleHeaderResponse] RX: 'Content-Type: text/html'
[HTTP-Client][handleHeaderResponse] RX: ''
[HTTP-Client][handleHeaderResponse] code: 400
HTTP code:400
[HTTP-Client][end] still data in buffer (794), clean up.
[HTTP-Client][end] tcp stop
```

As I've noticed, it is not getting the URL parameters properly when I concatenate the Strings. Any idea how to solve it?

Appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: It would help if you'd include the declaration and value of `userID` in your question given that this parameter is what you're having problems with.

Comment: @romkey, I updated the post.. Thanks!
I am getting the userID from the value stored in the EEPROM.

Comment: http error 400 is "Bad request". it is a response from the server

Comment: yes I understand.. but when I try to "hard code" the variable value in the string , I can get a success response `200`. So I think it's on the way I concatenate strings, but i'm not sure why.. been trying to figure it out for about 12 hours now..

Comment: how does your userId look like? perhaps there are a format error if you use special chars in the url. copy your url and try it in a browser or postman

Comment: it's actually just a number stored in the eeprom, but I am putting it in a String data type since the URL is also a String

Comment: I updated the post, please help. anyone?